# CMDActivityViewController crashing in iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

Getting crash in CMDActivityViewController for iOS8.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ArtViewController activityViewController:dataTypeIdentifiersForActivityType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7acb0b80'

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to this-**

In **dataTypesForActivityType method of "CMDActivityViewController.m"**, return nil , instead of the array dataTypes.

**Use this Method as it is**

```
- (NSArray *)dataTypesForActivityType:(NSString *)type {
         return nil;
}
```